# AdMob Interstitial: No ad to load (works on one project but not on another)

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've run into a very strange issue with AdMob. On my main project I receive error that there is no ad to load (when trying to fetch `GADInterstitial`).

However when I created a new project, copied the AdMob related sources, launched the project it loaded the ad without any problem (it looks like it always loads the test ad; I gave it few tries just to be sure).

On both projects I'm using the same Google pods:

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
```

I've been trying various solutions, generating different ad unit id's, tested the new project without analytics, then attached analytics to it. It worked like a charm during every step.

On my main project I got the ad once, strangely it was for ad unit id (banner view). Sadly since then I cannot get neither banner or interstitial ad (I couldn't retrieve the interstitial ad before).

My target platform is iOS 8+.

Sources, the `AdMobManager`

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class AdMobManager {
    static let sharedInstance = AdMobManager()

    private(set) var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    func loadInterstitialAd(delegate: GADInterstitialDelegate) -> GADInterstitial {
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "same-ad-unit-id-for-both-projects")
        interstitial.delegate = delegate

        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [ "same-test-id-for-both-projects" ]

        interstitial.loadRequest(request)
        return interstitial
    }
}
```

And the `ViewController`

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        interstitial = AdMobManager.sharedInstance.loadInterstitialAd(self)
    }
}

extension ViewController: GADInterstitialDelegate {
    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
        if interstitial.isReady {
            interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        } else {
            NSLog("Not ready")
        }
    }

    func interstitial(ad: GADInterstitial!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
        NSLog("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using same bundle identifier in both projects ,make sure  please.

Comment: There is no bundle id for AdMob, for analytics I've set proper bundle identifiers for both projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of my problem was custom `User-Agent`.

Hope that save somebody hours of debugging since AdMob documentation doesn't cover that.